# AWS EC2 instance fails consistently at 30 seconds on long page load

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I am running an `ECS` instance on `EC2` with an `application load balancer`, a `route53` domain, and a `RDS` db. This is an internal business application that I have restricted IP access to.

I have ran this app for 3 weeks with no issues. However, today the data that the web app ingests is an abnormally large size. This is not a mistake. Due to this though, a webpage is taking approximately 4 minutes to complete which I verified on my local machine it completes. However, running the same operation on AWS fails **at precisely 30 seconds every time**.

I have connected the app running on my local machine to my production `RDS` db and am able to download and upload the data with no issue. So there is no issue with the `RDS` db. In addition, this same functionality has worked previously and only failed today due to the large amount of data.

I spent hours with Amazon support to solve this issue but we couldn't figure it out. I am assuming it is a setting for one the AWS services I am using that has a `TTL` or `timeout` set to 30 seconds, but I couldn't find it in any of the services I am using:

- route53
- RDS
- ECS
- ECR
- EC2
- Load Balancer
- Target Group

Comment: Of those AWS services listed, I would check the Load Balancer connection timeout setting, which is 60 seconds by default.

Comment: I tried adjusting that setting with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

You have a backend instance timeout, likely in the web server config.

Right now your ELB has a timeout of 60 seconds, but your assets are failing at 30.

There are only a couple assets on AWS with hardcoded timeouts like that. I'm thinking (because this is the first time it's happened), you have one of the following:

Size limits in the upstream, or

Time limits on connection keep-alive

Look at your website server software (httpd/nginx). Nginx has something called "upstream.conf" where you can set upstream timeouts. I'm not sure of httpd does as well.

Resources:
https://serverfault.com/questions/414987/nginx-proxy-timeout-while-uploading-big-files

Answer (score 0):

From the NLB documentation, maybe relevant

`EC2 instances must respond to a new request within 30 seconds in order to establish a return path.`

I don't actually know what a return path is, nor what a 'response' is in this context since NLB has no concept of requests or responses.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/network-load-balancers.html#connection-idle-timeout

EDIT: Disregard, this must have to do with UDP NATing. 'Response' here is probably a packet going back from the EC2 instance to the client